# Convert MSL to WGS height

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, altitude

I need to find the coordinates for a given location in WGS coordinates. This mean geodetic latitude, longitude, and altitude (with respect to the reference ellipsoid).

I was informed the coordinates, but the altitude was given in MSL (mean sea level).

How do I perform this conversion? Is there a standard way/practice on how to do so?

Comment: do you have a raster (DTM) of your area of interest?
If yes you can use the [Point Sampling Tool plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointsamplingtool/) to extract the Altitude from your raster.


However, with the MSL value, you need to add the undulation of the geoid for your area.

Comment: The US government distributes a free tool called vDatum for doing various datum conversions.  https://vdatum.noaa.gov/

Comment: Yes, there is a standard way, and it begins with knowing which geoid your altitudes are related to.